# C#, Unity,Prism,xamarin

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I am new to xamarin and prism. When I try to create a cross platform project with xamarin and prism I encounter a problem. This is the start of my app.

The version of prism.form is 6.1-pre5.

The version of prism.unity is 6.2-pre3.

```
public class App : PrismApplication
    {

        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }

        protected override void InitializeModules()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            NavigationService.NavigateAsync<MainPage>();
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes()
        {
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
        }
    }
}
```

It builds successfully, but when I run the App, I get an exception:

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Prism.Unity.Navigation.UnityPageNavigationService", name = "(none)".

Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Prism.Unity.Navigation.UnityPageNavigationService(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container).

Exception is: MissingMethodException - Method 'PageNavigationService..ctor' not found.
```

---

At the time of the exception, the container was:

```
Resolving Prism.Unity.Navigation.UnityPageNavigationService,(none)

  Calling constructor Prism.Unity.Navigation.UnityPageNavigationService(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container)
.
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong NuGet package.  You need to be using Prism.Unity.Forms